How to Properly Propagate a JWT Token in gRPC Spring Boot from a ServerInterceptor to a Client Call?
I'm using grpc-spring-boot-starter to build a service, Service A, which acts as a proxy and subsequently calls another gRPC service, Service B. For authentication, we validate a JWT token received in the metadata of the initial client request. This token is validated and added to the current context using a ServerInterceptor in Service A.
Service A then uses a client to call Service B, but we want to propagate the same token in the client call. To do this I've followed a few different methods including this solution and this solution but in both cases the context token that was set in the ServerInterceptor was null.
I'm new to gRPC and Spring Boot, and I'm wondering if the issue might be related to the application spawning a new thread when making the client call to Service B, leading to a loss of context. How can I ensure the token is properly propagated across the service boundaries?
Any advice on how to correctly implement this, or insights into what might be going wrong, would be greatly appreciated!
I tried to take the context created in my ServerInterceptor to alter the metadate in my client calls to Service B. However the resulting value of the token was null leading me to believe that the context was either cancelled and a new thread was created at time of using the client to service B, or I am not calling the value in the context correctly.
